# How to use Kendo-ui grid for virtualization of remote data?

Tags: angularjs, telerik, kendo-ui-grid, data-virtualization

I'm using `kendo-ui` grid for `AngularJs` and want to activate `virtualization of remote data` functionality. For testing I have set `pageSize: 5`.
Below is description of `virtualization of remote data` from telerik site:

> There are cases when you may need to operate with large amount of data
>   in the grid, and fetching and processing this data at once would
>   impose a performance penalty due to limited browser resources.
>   Luckily, the Kendo UI grid has a solution called data virtualization
>   that alleviates any slowdowns when operating with huge volumes of
>   data. When enabled via the scrollable->virtual configuration option,
>   it displays a vertical scrollbar for the grid content and renders only
>   the number of items set via the pageSize property of the grid data
>   source. After you drag the scrollbar and the pageSize is exceeded, it
>   makes automatic requests to retrieve and render the next set of grid
>   rows. Both local and remote data are supported with the grid
>   virtualization feature, whereas in this demo the records are obtained
>   from a remote endpoint.

Also I have set following:

HTML:

```
<div kendo-grid k-options="mainGridOptions" id="historyGrid" style="width: auto;"></div>
```

JS for grid:

```
    var vm = $scope;
vm.viewMode = {
    mainGridOptions: {
    visible: true
    }
};
vm.mainGridOptions = {

            columns: [
                // here columns
            ],
            onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                vm.gridApi = gridApi;
            },
            dataSource: {
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            YearBalance: { type: 'number' },
                            Typezalezh: { type: 'string' },
                            License: { type: 'string' },
                            ObjectName: { type: 'string' },
                            ZalezhName: { type: 'string' },
                            PlastName: { type: 'string' },
                            Category: { type: 'string' },
                            Parameter: { type: 'string' },
                            LastVal: { type: 'string' },
                            Val: { type: 'string' },
                            Operation: { type: 'string' },
                            EndT: { type: 'date' }
                        }
                    }
                },

                pageSize: 5,
                transport: {
                    read: function(e) {
                        dataservice.getImportResultReport().then(function(data) {
                            e.success(JSON.parse(data));
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            height: screen.height - 330,
            minwidth : 1190,
            batch: true,
            scrollable: {
                virtual: true
            },
            sortable: true,

            serverSorting: true,
            filterable: {
                extra: false,
                operators: {
                    string: {
                        // here filters
                    },
                    number: {
                        // here filters
                    },
                    date: {
                        // here filters
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

On telerik site (Official website), it says that nothing more needs to be done. 
On scrolling, I should see a request to the server which in my case should be a `dataservice.getImportResultReport()` call. But this does't happen. This function is called only once and all data is returned.

May be it's occurring because I have not set `type: "odata"`? But I use data source of another type.

How to use this functionality?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `virtualization of remote data`? Do you want to display the data in kendo grid?

Comment: I added a description of this function.

Comment: Okay got it, can you also tell what html are you using to render kendo grid? The angularjs syntax looks good but I think you might have missed to add the directive in html

Comment: Please look. I think that the problem is that I do not use `type: 'odata'`. But the grid gets from the server JSON string...

Answer (score 0):

Add `k-scrollable` directive as follows in your html that renders your kendo grid:

```
<div kendo-grid k-data-source="mainGridOptions" k-scrollable="{virtual:true}"></div>
```

Also you have to use `k-data-source` directive for your dataSource. Hope it helps.

Working demo [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H0Kvs1i3UIaX8daMsxUe?p=preview)